# "that" usage, subject-verb distance

Tags: verbs, subjects, what-that

Which instruction is better:
1. Insert events that occurred at an earlier time to complement the events in the ‘present’ story.
2. insert events occurred at an earlier time to complement the events in the ‘present’ story.

Comment: *that* cannot be elided in all sentences. The sentence structure, syntax and semantics need to be considered and only if the use of *that* happens to be redundant can it be safely omitted. Not in this case, where either *that* or *which* needs to be used appropriately.

Comment: Basically, that means that _that_ (or any _Wh_-relative pronoun like _which_) can be deleted from a restrictive relative clause, provided it's not the subject of the clause. If it **is** the subject (as it is here) then it is required; otherwise it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

The *that* is required. #1 is better, but could it be simpler?

Would something like this work?

> Insert earlier events to complement the events in the ‘present’ story.

Comment: Great, thank you. Yes, I changed it to 'past events.'

Comment: You did **not** say why *that* is required, which would constitute the real answer. As it stands, it's a personal opinion, not a canonical answer. The major part of the present 'answer' deals with proof-reading/ writing advice, which is off-topic.

Comment: I've updated the question